# How to get Custom Log tables from Azure Log Analytics Workspace through PowerShell script?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am looking for a way to get all custom log tables from an Azure log analytics workspace through PowerShell code.

Below is an example of three custom log tables of which I would like to see the names in an object (array/list/...).

[image]

I am able to create a custom log table, insert and check data in it, but I am not able to upfront check if the table already exists, before I query on it.

I am using the `Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery` PowerShell cmdlet to query on the custom log table, but this fails if the log does not exist yet. Hence the question.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have created sample custom log tables

[image]

and executed the below command

```cs
Get-AzOperationalInsightsDataSource -Kind CustomLog -ResourceGroupName RGName -WorkspaceName LogAnalyticsWorkSpaceName
```

[image]

`Get-AzOperationalInsightsDataSource` -  Gets datasources under Azure Log Analytics workspace.